# Backbone - Passing index into View when iterating over a Collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to render a View which needs to know the index position of the Model passed in inside its Collection:

**Parent View**

```
collection.each(function($_v, $_k) {
    (new view({model: $_v, index: $_k})).render();
});
```

**Child View**

```
className: function() {
    0 === this.index % 2 ? 'colored' : '';
}
```

However it appears that `this.index` can't be set this way and become `undefuined`. What is the proper to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
className: function() {
    0 === this.options.index % 2 ? 'colored' : '';
}
```

Comment: That's an intriguing design... Probably to foolproof people trying to overwrite View.render or something similar on instantiation. Thanks for the answer =)